# How to sum second array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, sum

I want to sum a 2d list.
Example:
`x==[[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]]`

a solution should lool like:
`sum_2d = [3, 7, 11]`

I tried this:
`y = sum(sum(x,[]))`
but that sums all the numbers.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Your current way is to sum all nums in one shot.  Just loop each sub-list and answer is there.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=[[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]]

[sum(y) for y in x]

#output
[3, 7, 11]
```

using list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate over x, and use sum() at each row of x:

```
x = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

sum_2d = []

for i in x:
    sum_2d += [sum(i)]
    
print(sum_2d)
```